# Sql : How to calculate table values using formula

Tags: sql, mysqli

Here is original Query :, it generates o/p with two columns name (label, count) :

```
label      count 
Fails      1
Pass       3
```

and here is query I wrote which generates above data

```
select r.pname as resolution
,lb.label
,count(r.pname) as occurences
from issuelink
inner join jiraissue p on issuelink.source = p.id
inner join jiraissue c on issuelink.destination = c.id
inner join issuelinktype t on issuelink.linktype = t.id
inner join resolution r on c.resolution = r.id
inner join issuestatus istat on p.issuestatus = istat.sequence
inner join label lb on c.id = lb.issue
where t.linkname = 'jira_subtask_link'
and p.pkey in (@pkey)
and c.issuetype in ('13')
and r.pname not in ('Fails Smoke Test - General Failure', 'Fails Smoke Test - New Firmware Available')
and label in ('SmokeTest', 'fullcert', 'bfv', 'papercert')
group by r.pname;
```

As per your suggestion I tried using cross function, however its throwing an error of "please check syntax":

```
select  100.0 * fail.cnt / (fail.cnt + pass.cnt) as c
from    (
        select  r.pname as label
        ,       count(r.pname) as cnt
        from issuelink
        inner join jiraissue p on issuelink.source = p.id
        inner join jiraissue c on issuelink.destination = c.id
        inner join issuelinktype t on issuelink.linktype = t.id
        inner join resolution r on c.resolution = r.id
        inner join issuestatus istat on p.issuestatus = istat.sequence
        inner join label lb on c.id = lb.issue
        where t.linkname = 'jira_subtask_link'
        and p.pkey in ('SRPDTVTPV-3')
        and c.issuetype in ('13')
        and r.pname not in ('Fails Smoke Test - General Failure', 'Fails Smoke Test - New Firmware Available')
        and label in ('SmokeTest', 'fullcert', 'bfv', 'papercert')
        group by r.pname
        ) as fail
cross join    
        (
        select  r.pname as label
        ,       count(r.pname) as cnt
        from issuelink
        inner join jiraissue p on issuelink.source = p.id
        inner join jiraissue c on issuelink.destination = c.id
        inner join issuelinktype t on issuelink.linktype = t.id
        inner join resolution r on c.resolution = r.id
        inner join issuestatus istat on p.issuestatus = istat.sequence
        inner join label lb on c.id = lb.issue
        where t.linkname = 'jira_subtask_link'
        and p.pkey in ('SRPDTVTPV-3')
        and c.issuetype in ('13')
        and r.pname not in ('Fails Smoke Test - General Failure', 'Fails Smoke Test - New Firmware Available')
        and label in ('SmokeTest', 'fullcert', 'bfv', 'papercert')

        group by r.pname
        ) as pass
where   fail.label = 'Fails Certification'
        and pass.label = 'Passes Certification'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using a `cross join`:

```
select  100.0 * a.count / (a.count + b.count) as c
from    YourQuery a
cross join    
        YourQuery b
where   a.label = 'a'
        and b.label = 'b'
```

Here's another approach using aggregates, a bit more tricky but only uses YourQuery once:

```
select  100.0 * cnt_a / (cnt_a + cnt_b) as c
from    (
        select  max(case when label = 'a' then count end) as cnt_a
        ,       max(case when label = 'b' then count end) as cnt_b
        from    YourQuery
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Comment: Hi Andomar, label and count are headers of the o/p table, would that still work ?

Comment: What do you mean by "header"?  Is it a leading row?  If so, what are your column names?  Perhaps you can show an example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: my column names are label and count.

Comment: Ok that's what I guessed, this answer should work for that?  If it doesn't, please post an error or problem that occurs.

Comment: Getting error on sql syntax, editing question and pasting the query.

Comment: Pasted the query in the body of this page.

Comment: Looks like your just missing parenthesis `()`, I updated the query in your answer

Comment: Hi Andomar,It doesn't like .count on first line after 100.0 * 'Fails Certification', says "you have an error in your sql syntax......"

Comment: Ah ok, if you alias a table to `a` you've got to refer to it like `a`.  Updated query again.  Also renamed `count` to `cnt`, it's better to avoid using a keyword as a column name.